# Non Muslim getting goosebumps hearing Islamic prayer? Is this a sign?

Tags: nikah, dua, non-muslim

I hope you are well.

I had my nikah today (my husband is a Muslim, I have been raised as a Catholic but have a strong interest to Islam)

Today when the Maulana was praying (I had never heard an Islamic prayer before - I don’t think, and obviously didn’t know what he was saying) but I got goosebumps across my whole body. I feel like it was a sign that although my brain couldn’t *understand* what was being said, my heart resonated with it.

My apologies if this comes across as a silly question / statement for opinion but I am very keen to know others thoughts.

I am not closed to converting however I know I have a lot more to learn and understand before doing so, and feel like today was my first sign I am on the right path.

Wishing you all well,

Many thanks.

Comment: for some reasons extremely common, non-arabic people listening to Quran and feeling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you felt a connection with the Quran. The recitation of the book does that you. I would recommend listening to some Quran reciations online, such as on youtube, especially with the translations. Here are some short recitations that are sure to get you emotional (especially when you read the translations):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz-OE6IgDYM&ab_channel=SAmir

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dn60yPZG3A&ab_channel=MercifulServant

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hV5JAcpCv1U&ab_channel=AbuHurairaCenter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gZgO9GW8uk&list=PLK1jHCbKdi08YJCjdTm7opMQ8dZWcUjcL&ab_channel=SyedAhmed

Answer (score 2):

Allah is inviting you to accept Islam. Allah says that he invites open-minded, truth seeker Jews and Christians to Islam.

Allah says in the Glorious Qur'an,

And thus We have sent down to you (O Muhammad) the book (this Qur’an) (same way as the Torah to Moses and Gospel to Jesus). So those whom We gave the Scripture (Jews and the Christians) believe in it, and some of these pagans also believe in it, and none but the disbelievers reject Our Verses. (Glorious Qur'an 29:47)

You are not the first one to witness this sign of Allah Almighty. There are many Non-Muslims who witnessed the sign of truth of Islam when they hear the Qur'an.

Allah says in the Glorious Qur'an,

"The ones who believe and their hearts are peaceful with the remembrance of Allah. Listen, the hearts find peace only in the remembrance of Allah" (Glorious Qur'an 13:28)

Allah says that he guides those who strive hard to find the truth,

And those who struggle in our cause, We will surely, guide them (to) Our ways. And indeed, Allah surely (is) with the good-doers. (Glorious Qur'an 29:69)

There are many Non-Muslims who find peace when they listen to the Qur'an.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://quran.com/5:83